# Touch events are not firing on inputs iOS8 standalone web app

Tags: javascript, dom-events, ios8, iphone-standalone-web-app

In a **standalone web-app** launched from homescreen, on **iOS 8.1(8.0)**,
touch events (`touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend`) are not firing on inputs/textareas, but on the same device in Safari they are.

I've tested the same web-app on **iOS 6** and everything works as expected.

Has anyone encountered the same problem and found workaround for this issue?
Maybe there is official bug report? Unfortunately, I've found nothing on this subject.

Comment: Are they not getting fired at all or are they getting fired multiple times (in effect making it look like they never got fired)?What is your app built on? What framework? More details pls

Comment: I've tested this using simple HTML+jQuery page that contains textarea and inputs. Looks like they are not getting fired at all.

Comment: first: have you validated that jQuery is running? second: can you share you registration for tap events?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3ssj6fpz/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that touchevents in a standalone web-apps launched from homescreeen are back with iOS 8.1.3
:-)

Comment: can you provide a source please?

Comment: What kind of source do you mean? What do you mean by "source" - english is not my first language. My code is just working again. Did not work with 8.0 to 8.1.2

Comment: ah ok, I meant "citation" or something, I was thinking you read that from some official source or whatever :)